# UIKit layouts subviews even though it was not asked to

Tags: ios, swift, user-interface, autolayout, constraints

I was messing with layoutSubviews method in UIViewControllers. I assumed that when you override layoutSubviews on the view, it doesn't layout its subviews, but that wasn't the case, the view and its subviews were correctly laid out.

```
class Vieww: UIView {
    override func didMoveToSuperview() {
        super.didMoveToSuperview()
        let centered = UIView()
        addSubview(centered)
        centered.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        backgroundColor = .green
        centered.backgroundColor = .red
        centered.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: widthAnchor, multiplier: 1/2).isActive = true
        centered.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: heightAnchor, multiplier: 1/2).isActive = true
        centered.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: centerYAnchor).isActive = true
        centered.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: centerXAnchor).isActive = true
    }
    override func layoutSubviews() {
        print("layoutSubviews")
    }
}

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        view.backgroundColor = .white
        view.layout(Vieww()).center().leading(20).trailing(20).height(400)
    }
}
```

I expected that because I was not calling layoutSubviews, my views wouldn't be laid out, but I get layout like if I did override this method.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Read the docs: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiview/1622482-layoutsubviews

> "the default implementation uses any constraints you have set to determine the size and position of any subviews. Subclasses can override this method as needed to perform more precise layout of their subviews."

Comment: And what? The default implementation does somethings, but I am opting out of default implementation

Comment: Overriding `layoutSubviews()` does not remove existing constraints.... it allows you to perform other, specific layout tasks. One very common use is to update layer frames, as those are not updated by auto-layout. Do some searching and reading up on Layout Life Cycle - here's a decent article that addresses `layoutSubviews()`: https://www.vadimbulavin.com/view-auto-layout-life-cycle/

Comment: In this article it is said that ```During this step(Layout step), frames of each view are updated with the rectangles calculated in the Update phase```. Doesn't it mean that all frames are set in ```layoutSubviews()```?. if that's the case, then shouldn't we get no results if this method is empty? If I correctly understood, ```updateConstraints()``` does all the tasks for computation, and ```layoutSubviews()``` apply these computations